# Powershell: Export a custom object to a CSV file - extract a single property value with Select-Object

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv, select-object

I wrote a script that constructs a custom object and exports it to a CSV file:

```
$reg = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\McAfee\DLP\Agent | Select-Object agentversion

$date = Get-ItemProperty 'C:\Program Files\McAfee' | Select-Object {$_.LastWriteTime} 

$date86 = Get-ItemProperty 'C:\Program Files (x86)\McAfee'| Select-Object {$_.LastWriteTime}

New-Object -TypeName pscustomobject -Property @{
  "Number1"=$reg
  "Number2"=$date86
  "Number3"=$date } | export-csv -Path C:\****\desktop\stuff.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

and the data row in the resulting CSV file is:

> "@{AgentVersion=9.4.112.22}","@{$*.LastWriteTime=5/6/2016 6:02:32 AM}","@{$*.LastWriteTime=7/5/2016 8:34:01 PM}"

Is it possible to get rid of the unwanted `@{<name>=...}` wrappers?

Answer (score 1):

The expression:

```
Select-Object {$_.LastWriteTime}
```

outputs an object with a single property with name `$_.LastWriteTime`. The simplest way to fix it is to use the `-ExpandProperty` parameter which will only output the value that you are interested in. e.g.:

```
$date86 = Get-ItemProperty 'C:\Program Files (x86)\McAfee'|
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty LastWriteTime
```

Note that I've also removed the script block from the `Select-Object` command, as it wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

To complement [zdan's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38318050/45375)<sup>[1]</sup>
with alternatives:

If you just want the *value* of a given object's property, simply wrap the command in `(...)` and use `.<propertyName>`:

```sh
(Get-ItemProperty 'C:\Program Files\McAfee').LastWriteTime # returns a [datetime] instance
```

In PSv3+, the above also works with commands returning *multiple* items (arrays), in which case an *array* of the input items' individual property values is output - this feature is called [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375).

---

PSv3 introduced a shortcut syntax for `%` / `ForEach-Object` (and also `?` / `Where-Object`) that can be leveraged here as well :

```sh
Get-ItemProperty 'C:\Program Files\McAfee' | % LastWriteTime # ditto
```

This is the equivalent of the more verbose (which also works in PSv2-):

```sh
Get-ItemProperty 'C:\Program Files\McAfee' | % { $_.LastWriteTime }
```

These two pipeline-based syntax forms are slower, but have two advantages:

- Large input collections are better processed in pipelines one by one in order to keep memory use constant (if feasible; if you need to collect the entire output in memory, there is no advantage).
- This syntax unambiguously references an *individual item*'s property rather than a property of the *collection as a whole*.

  - E.g., `(Get-ChildItem -File C:\Windows).Length` returns the *count* of files in `C:\Windows`, because `Length` is interpreted as the *collection*'s (array's) property;
    by contrast, `Get-ChildItem -File C:\Windows | % Length` returns an array of the individual files' `.Length` (file-size) property values.

Finally, in PSv4+, you may also use the [`.ForEach()` collection *method*](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/10/22/foreach-and-where-magic-methods/), which doesn't use the pipeline and is therefore faster (though slightly slower than member-access enumeration), but, like member-access enumeration, requires that the input collection be in memory in full:

```sh
(Get-ItemProperty 'C:\Program Files\McAfee').ForEach('LastWriteTime')
```

---

[1] A quick overview of **[`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object)'s behavior**:

- `Select-Object [-Property] <string[]>` returns a *custom object* for each input object, containing only the specified properties; even with only a *single* property specified, the results are custom objects with that single property, not the property values themselves.
- By contrast, using `-ExpandProperty <string>` returns the given, single property's *value* from each input object (typed as-is) instead.

A simple example: extract the `Year` property value from a `Get-Date` call:

```sh
# WRONG: with (implied) -Property
PS> $val = Get-Date | Select-Object Year; "$val"
@{Year=2018}  # !!
# A custom object with a Year property was returned and the above is its
# string representation, the equivalent of:
#      "$([pscustomobject] @{ Year = 2018 })"

# CORRECT: with -ExpandProperty
PS> $val = Get-Date | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Year; "$val"
2018  # OK: -ExpandProperty extracted just the property's *value*
```